# Mixture of water, methanol and dichloromethane

Tags: thermodynamics, solubility

If I have a mixture of 25 vol% methanol in water and I mix it with an equal volume of dichloromethane (which is miscible with methanol but not water) can I roughly say that both phases (i.e. water and dichloromethane) will have the same methanol concentration upon reaching equilibrium? Or will it vary significantly based on the activity of each mixture?

Comment: I doubt it. I would expect the MeOH to go into the water phase

Comment: When you have two phases they is always some of each component in both phases.  // (solubility of dichloromethane in pure water is 17.5 g/L @ 25 °C) // I'd expect the dichloromethane to contain both water and methanol, and the methanol/water phase will contain a small amount of dichloromethane. In certain proportions I'd expect one phase.

Comment: What is needed is the ternary phase diagram for the methanol/water/dichloromethane system. // I looked and couldn't find one. But there must have been studies on this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial phase diagram. That seems to indicate that systems with roughly 50% methanol are miscible.

Source: http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/9995/11/11_chapter%206.pdf

[image]